# How can I use Redis in my Ruby on Rails application with Windows OS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

First of all I am sorry for my newbie question, but I am kinda stuck here.
Could anyone please tell me step by step how to use Redis in my Rails 6 application, if I have Windows OS?
I have installed Redis, currently it is in my C:\Program Files,
[with these files inside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL14X.png)

I started the redis-server.exe, when it starts running it says:

```
[8020] 20 Nov 17:26:06 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. 
In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'

[8020] 20 Nov 17:26:06 * Server started, Redis version 2.4.6

[8020] 20 Nov 17:26:06 # Open data file dump.rdb: No such file or directory

[8020] 20 Nov 17:26:06 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6
379

[8020] 20 Nov 17:26:07 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 672768 bytes in use

[8020] 20 Nov 17:26:12 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 672768 bytes in use

[8020] 20 Nov 17:26:17 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 672768 bytes in use
```

.......... (it just keep outputs this same text every 5 seconds)

Also in my Rails application, I configured some things. I changed config/cable.yml file to:

```
development:
adapter: redis
url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
adapter: test

production:
adapter: redis
url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
channel_prefix: actioncable_test_production
```

My concept was to create a channel, named 'room', and output a message in the console, to see its successfully connected. But my problem is that it doesn't output anything.

I set app/javascript/channels/room_channel.js to:

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("RoomChannel", {
connected() {
// Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
console.log("Connected succesfully!")
},

disconnected() {
// Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
},

received(data) {
// Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
}
});
```

and my app/channels/room_channel.rb file to:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
def subscribed
stream_from "room_channel"
end

def unsubscribed
# Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
end
end
```

Also, on my command prompt shows this: (after the usual rendering messages and things like that):

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-11-20 18:24:05 +0100
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-11-20 18:24:06 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-a
live, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

When I go to the browser console, it says Firefox cannot create connection with ws://localhost:3000/cable

Any idea what's the problem here?
Thanks for the answers and best regards, Rererbit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very old and deprecated version of Redis, an abandoned project by Microsoft called OpenTech Redis.

I suggest you checkout Memurai.
Memurai is an up-to-date native Windows port of Redis that derives from that project (see [this commit](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/commit/287e01c68ce9ec6e7a739c19b04b1dfc253326e3)).

Memurai is also available with a free Developer Edition.

Disclaimer: I work in Memurai.